# Python for loop iteration using lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop, graph, closures

```
closur=[]
i=6
dis_tn=distance[i]
headnode=x
for k in headers[headnode]:
    if distance[k]<=dis_tn:
                    if i in headers[k]:
                      closur.append(x)
                      closur.append(k)
                      closur.append(i)
                    else:
                        #break
                        headnode=k
                        continue
print "Closure of (",x,",",i,")= ",closur
```

In the above given code, in the else part, i need headnode=k and in the next iteration, the for loop needs to take the value of k. 
for eg: if, headers[headnode]=headers[0]==[5,3,1]
                              headers[5]==[4,1]

In the first iteration, 5 will be taken., and if, the if condition is not satisfied, in the else part, the value of the headnode becomes 5 and for the second iteration i need the headers[5] to be taken. But here it takes the next headers[0], ie., 3 instead of 4.

what changes should be done so that the above problem gets solved??

Comment: You can transform it into a while loop, and increment k inside the loop. Do you have a simplified, self-containing example that we can try out as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for-loop keeps itarating over the list `headers[headnode]`. So you can not change the itaration-list by reinitializing `headnode`. From your description above, the following code should do what you want.

```
closur=[]
i=6
dis_tn=distance[i]
headnode=x
dont_break = True
while dont_break:
    dont_break = False
    for k in headers[headnode]:
        if distance[k]<=dis_tn:
            if i in headers[k]:
                closur.append(x)
                closur.append(k)
                closur.append(i)
            else:
                headnode=k
                dont_break = True
                break
print "Closure of (",x,",",i,")= ",closur
```

Answer (score 1):

headers[node] has generate a iterable object, it's static. In the loop, each iteration get the value by call the next() method.